# Auth login doesn't work in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have written a users controller which should login a user if the submitted username and passwort (encrypted with cakephp's Security::hash() => e.g. `6b0deec0d563224524da45691584643bc78c96ea`, no additional hash settings) matches a row in the database. But it doesn't work and I don't have any idea why.

This is a snippet of my **UsersController.php**

```
public function add() {
    $this->set("title_for_layout", "Register");

    if($this->request->is("post")) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);

    if($this->User->save(array("password" => Security::hash($this->request->data["User"]["password"])))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__("Successfully registred."), "flash_success");
            $this->redirect("/login");
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__("Validation failed."), "flash_danger");
    }
    }
}
```

The registration works fine and a row in the database is created where I have the colums "username" which contains the plain username e.g. "myuser" and "password" which contains a hashed string. I don't think that the problem could be solved here.

This is another snippet of my **UsersController.php**

```
public function login() {
    $this->set("title_for_layout", "Login");

    if($this->request->is("post")) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Login successfull.", "flash_success");
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Login failed.", "flash_danger");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the view **login.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input("username"); ?>
<?= $this->Form->password("password"); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end("submit"); ?>
```

And here's my problem: The login always fail. Additionally I don't have any settings in the `$component` array.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You should not manually hash in the controller. See the documentation on [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/). Also calling save() with data passed after set() sounds like sth that can easily break. And for the sake of  completness: you are also missing create().

Comment: Now I've changed the way, a new user will be saved but that doesn't solve my problem. The data which are saved in the db are the same than before (but this new way is cleaner, thanks). Now I've found out, that the sql query for `$this->Auth->login()` only looks for the username in the db and not for the password. The query looks like this: `[...]'users' AS 'User' WHERE 'User'.'username' = 'xxx' LIMIT 1`. But where is the password in the query?

Comment: Try `$this->Form->input("password")` even though both should work. And post your controller Auth configuration. That is probably where your configuration is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using cakePHP 2.x then you can set password encryption in the model's callback function beforeSave() as

```
<?php
// app/Model/User.php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {

// ...

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}

?>
```

For more information follow the [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html). IF you still want to encrypt password in the controller then you can use the code like.

```
public function add() {
    $this->set("title_for_layout", "Register");

    if($this->request->is("post")) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);

    if($this->User->save(array("password" => $this->Auth->password($this->request->data["User"]["password"])))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__("Successfully registred."), "flash_success");
            $this->redirect("/login");
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__("Validation failed."), "flash_danger");
    }
    }
}

?>
```

If you're using the cakePHP 2.4 or later then follow the documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords).